# Jquery: How to focus on last character of DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a contenteditable DIV.

1. I want to focus on last character when a text is added.

HTML:

```
<div id="messageBox" contenteditable="true" class="message"></div>
```

I tried but this code does not right:
[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j8qk6j1k/)

2. How to create a new line and the cursor focus there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the help of some javascript. Here is an example of setting the cursor to the end of the text

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/kpLk4vsL/)

```
<div id="messageBox" contenteditable="true" class="message"></div>
<input type='button' class='btn' value='button'>
```

---

```
function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
            && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        range.collapse(false);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}

$('.btn').click(function() {

    $('#messageBox').html('ok');

    placeCaretAtEnd($('#messageBox').get(0));
});
```